Catch last name from email
could someone help me out to get only the last name from email address ? Example email: John.Snow@test.com
I would like to get only "Snow". I made formula to get first name but how can I get the last name ?
Formula to get first name:
UPPER(LEFT((LEFT({!$Record.FromAddress}, FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress})-1)), 1))&LOWER(RIGHT((LEFT({!$Record.FromAddress}, FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress})-1)), Len((LEFT({!$Record.FromAddress}, FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress})-1)))-1))


Your use case can have many exceptions, especially if the left-side doesn't have any dots or separators.  What will you do then?

Problem is solved by below formula
UPPER(MID({!$Record.FromAddress}, FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress}) + 1, 1)) & LOWER(MID({!$Record.FromAddress}, FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress}) + 2, FIND("@", {!$Record.FromAddress}) - FIND(".", {!$Record.FromAddress}) - 2))

